# AngularJS modifying the transcluded content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a syntax highlighting directive.

Basically a directive like so:

```
<div syntax-highlight="language">{{codeValue}}</div>
```

Should be turned into:

```
<div syntax-highlight="language">
    <pre><code>{{codeValue that has been syntax highlighted with span tags}}</code></pre>
</div>
```

So what I have is:

```
return {
    scope: {
        'syntaxHighlight': '@'
    },
    template: '<pre><code ng-transclude></code></pre>',
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller, transclude) {

    }
};
```

When this code currently runs, everything that is inside the `{{codeValue}}` which is basically a string gets put into `<code ng-transclude></code>` while being wrapped in a `span` element.

This is not good because I don't just want a string inside the `code` element. I need to modify this value prior to being transcluded.

I need to pass this `{{codeValue}}` into a syntax highlighting function which will return the syntax highlighted code which will be raw HTML (so a raw string (sanitized and escaped) gets turned into HTML with span tags). This raw HTML then needs to be put inside `code` element.

I've tried using the transclude function, but it seems like the content has already been transcluded.

Comment: I assume you are calling the syntax highlighting function within your link function? Can you not just append to your element therein?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
['$sce', function($sce){

    return {
        scope: {
            'syntaxLanguage': '@'
        }, 
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: codeBlockTemplate, 
        transclude: true, 
        replace: true, 
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller, transclude) {

            //transclude's clone is children elements of the directive element, it will wrap any unwrapped text nodes with the span tag
            transclude(scope, function (clone) {

                //get the directive element's content as text, this will be the {{code}}
                var code = angular.element(clone).text();

                //convert the code string into a highlighted code string
                var highlightedCode = hljs.highlight(scope.syntaxLanguage, code, true);

                //bind to the scope as trusted HTML
                scope.highlightedCode = $sce.trustAsHtml(highlightedCode.value);

            });

        }
    };

}]
```

With this as the template:

```
<pre><code ng-bind-html="highlightedCode"></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to pass CodeValue to the directive and manipulate it in the link function?

what about:

`<syntaxhighlight codevalue="codeValue"> </syntaxhighlight>`

```
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {'codevalue': '='},
     template: '<div> <pre><code ><span>{{sanitizedText}}</span></code></pre></div> ',
     replace: true,
     link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {

       scope.sanitizedText = textEditingFunction(scope.codevalue); //pass codevalue to the modifying function, who will return the sanitized text

    }
};
```

Comment: Whats the point of `transclude: true`? You end not using any transclusion tools. I did end up doing something very similar. Furthermore, it doesn't match my use case, as the code value would be inside the `<syntaxHighlight>` element.